# Estou tentando fazer um pequeno slide de imagem

Tags: javascript

```
var cont = 0;
var imgss = [];
var refrescar = 1;

imgss[0] = "../_imagem/primerr.png";
imgss[1] = "../_imagem/cab.png";

function contar (){

    document.images.item(0).src = imgss[cont++];
        if(cont == 1){

        }
        setTimeout("contar()", refrescar * 2000);
}
window.opener = contar()
```

Mas me atrapalhei nesse `if` e não consigo fazer o contador voltar na imagem para repetir de novo.

Comment: Se so forem duas imagens, e os índices são 0 e 1, pode fazer um "toggle" `cont = !cont`

Comment: maus mano que sou meio nobb nesses operadores boto esse cont=!cont no if ou em baixo?

Comment: A pergunta antes é, serão somente duas imagens?

Comment: so duas kk
pq tem q ser mais pra dar certo?

Comment: Coloca o código HTML ao menos. Para que assim possamos criar uma resposta interessante.

Comment: no html ta so a tag <img> com src que tou buscando com document.images

Comment: Seria interessante colocar, por que se não falasse não teria como descobrir :|

Answer (score 2):

Desse jeito funciona:

```js
var cont = 0;
var imgs = [];
var refrescar = 1;

imgs[0] = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg";
imgs[1] = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg";

function contar() {
  cont = 1 - cont;
  document.images.item(0).src = imgs[cont];
  setTimeout("contar()", refrescar * 2000);
}
window.opener = contar()
```

```html
<img/>
```

Basicamente funciona como um toggle, usei como referencia essa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911235/is-there-a-better-way-of-writing-v-v-0-1-0) no SOen.

```
cont = 1 - 1; // 0
cont = 1 - 0; // 1
```

E por ai vai, infinitamente

---

Caso você quisesse ter mais imagens:

```js
var cont = 2;
var imgs = [];
var refrescar = 1;

imgs[0] = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg";
imgs[1] = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg";
imgs[2] = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMglq.png?s=32&g=1";

function contar() {
  cont = (imgs.length - 1 === cont ? 0 : ++cont );
  document.images.item(0).src = imgs[cont];
  setTimeout("contar()", refrescar * 2000);
}
window.opener = contar()
```

```html
<img/>
```

Comment: mano esse ta só exibindo a segunda imagem e da error

Comment: Clique no executar e veja funcionando aqui mesmo =], provavelmente errou em alguma coisa

Comment: assim kk tinha esqueçido de tirar o ++ do imgs[cont++];

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o operador `%` (resto de divisão) para que o índice sempre esteja dentro do `length` do array, é uma solução mais matemática e faz com que sempre funcione, pois depende do tamanho do array.

O resto de divisão sempre vai ser um número entre `0` e o `divisor - 1`, ou seja, `x % 5` sempre vai ser 0, 1, 2, 3 ou 4.

Aí basta incrementar o índice e usar o resto de divisão para criar um ciclo.

```
for(let i=0 ; i < numero_qualquer ; i++) {
    console.log(i % 5);
}
// Printa: 0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,...
```

```js
var imagens = [
    'https://via.placeholder.com/150/ff0000/ffffff',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/150/00ff00/ffffff',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000ff/ffffff',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/150/ff00ff/ffffff',
];

var img = document.getElementById('imagem');
var i = 0;
var l = imagens.length;

function slide() {
  i = (i + 1) % l;
  img.src = imagens[i];
}

setInterval(slide, 2000);
```

```html
<img id="imagem" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/ff0000/ffffff">
```

---

Isso resolve o problema em específico, porém uma maneira mais interessante de fazer esse slide seria adicionando todas as `<img>` em um container, aplicar um CSS e ir esconde/mostrando as outras imagens. Dessa maneira, ao carregar a página, todas suas imagens já estarão baixadas e prontas pra uso.

Ex.:

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var i = 0;
var imgs = container.querySelectorAll('img');
var l = imgs.length

function slide() {
  imgs[i].classList.remove('active');
  i = (i + 1) % l;
  imgs[i].classList.add('active');
}

setInterval(slide, 2000);
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}

#container > img {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms linear;
}

#container > img.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img class="active" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/ff0000/ffffff"/>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/00ff00/ffffff"/>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000ff/ffffff"/>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/ff00ff/ffffff"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Gosto mais da sua solução =]

Comment: O bom é que desse jeito é só substituir `i = (i + 1) % l` por `i = (i + 1) % imagens.length` que dá pra ir adicionando imagens dinamicamente. :D